# sed command replace muti line with reg

Tags: shell, sed

I got a text like this:

```
TOKEN = decrypt_aes(
    "189272123124aqephkiz3")
```

And I want to change it into:

```
TOKEN = "189272123124aqephkiz3"
```

How can I make this?
I can do this when it`s in a single line with following command:`enter code here`

```
sed -i "s/decrypt_aes(\(.*\))/\1/g"
```

But I don`t no how to do when its in multi line

Comment: This might help: [grep regular expression match for newline character is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72704877/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```bash
sed -i '/.*decrypt_aes($/{N;s/^\([^=]*=\).*\(".*"\))$/\1 \2/}' file
```

*Details*:

- `/.*decrypt_aes($/` - matches a line that ends with `decrypt_aes(` substring, and if it matches, the block that follows is executed
- `N` - append a newline and the next line to the pattern space
- `s/^\([^=]*=\).*\(".*"\))$/\1 \2/` - replaces

  - `^\([^=]*=\).*\(".*"\))$` - start of string in the pattern space (`^`), any zero or more chars other than `=` and then a `=` are captured into Group 1 (`\1`), then any text (`.*`), then a `"..."` substring (captured into Group 2 (`\2`)) and then a `)` at the end of string
  - `\1 \2` is the replacement pattern, which is Group 1 value + space + Group 2 value.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/vUhfZ1):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='TOKEN = decrypt_aes(
    "189272123124aqephkiz3")'

sed '/.*decrypt_aes($/{N;s/^\([^=]*=\).*\(".*"\))$/\1 \2/}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
TOKEN = "189272123124aqephkiz3"
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file contains only the two lines you showed, then this might help with GNU sed:

```
sed -i 'N; s/decrypt_aes(\n *//; s/)//' file
```

From `man sed`:

> `N`: Append the next line of input into the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/decrypt_aes.*\(".*"\).*/\1/;P;D' file
```

Append the following line and if the combined lines matches `decrpty_aes` followed by `"..."`, replace the match by the string `"..."`.

N.B. If no match is found, each line will be printed as is.